# Plot multiple columns against a single column in one plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe with 9 columns, including a column for elapsed time (Days):

```
Probes <- data.frame(Days=seq(0.01, 4.91, 0.01), DJ1=-45:445, SJ2=-50:440, SJ3=10:500, SJ4=-200:290, DJ2=-150:340, DJ9=100:590, SJ21=-300:190, SJ32=-100:390)
```

I would like to create a line graph with multiple series on one plot. I would be plotting EACH of the remaining columns in the data frame against the first column (Days).

I know the basic code to do this...However, I am wondering if there is a simpler option for when you would like to plot ALL of the columns in the dataframe against one column, as I am doing now.  It seems redundant to have to type a line of code for every single column name, particularly because I have to this on over 50 data frames.

For my particular dataset, I would like to color the columns with "S" in the header as "brown" and the columns with "D" in the header as orange.

The long and unwieldy code I have for this is written below so that you can see the output I am going for. Is there a simpler way to this (perhaps in ggplot)?

```
png("ProbesPlot.png", height = 1000, width = 1400, units = "px", res = 200)
par(xpd=T, mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,6))
plot(Probes$Days, Probes$DJ1, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="orange", main="Depth in Sediments- 4.5 cm", xlab="Elapsed Time (days)", ylab="Eh (mV)", xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(-400,600), bty="n") 
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$SJ2, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="brown")
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$SJ3, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="brown")
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$SJ4, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="brown")
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$DJ2, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="orange ")
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$DJ9, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="orange ")
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$SJ21, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="brown")
lines(Probes$Days, Probes$SJ32, type="l", lwd=2, lty=1, col="brown")
legend(8.5,400, c("4 cm", "1 cm"), lty=c(1,1),  lwd=c(2,2), col=c("orange", " brown"), bty="n", title="Depth") 
dev.off()
```

3/1 Edit to question @eipi10  I have an additional dataframe with 29 columns including a column for elapsed time (Days).  I would like to create the same type of plot, but instead of 2 color categories (D and S) I now have 3 (D, M, and S).  This is an example of the structure of my new dataframe:

```
Probes <- data.frame(Days=seq(0.01, 4.91, 0.01), B1D.J1=-45:445, B1S.J2=-50:440, B1M.J3=10:500, B1S.J4=-200:290, B1D.J25=-150:340, B1D.J9=100:590, B1S.J21=-300:190, B1S.J32=-100:390, B1D.J18=-15:475, B1M.J22=-70:420, B1M.J31=5:495, B1S.J43=-200:290, B1D.J27=-150:340, B1D.J99=100:590, B1S.J87=-300:190, B1S.J65=-100:390, B1S.J44=-300:190, B1M.J90=-100:390, B1D.J18=-15:475, B1M.J26=-70:420, B1M.J66=5:495, B1M.J43=-200:290, B1D.J52=-150:340, B1D.J96=-50:440, B1M.J53=-300:190, B1M.J74=-100:390)
```

Also, the only legend I would essentially need is a small one differentiating the colors: Orange=Deep, Brown= Mid, Red=Shallow (D, M, and S)

Comment: For complicated tasks you would be better off learning something more powerful like `ggplot2`, `lattice`, or `ggvis`. They more easily accommodate this and much more besides.

Comment: Also `matplot()` from `graphics` can do that. The package `graphics` is part of the standard installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @MikeWise's suggestion, here's how you can make this much easier with `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

Probes <- data.frame(Days=seq(0.01, 4.91, 0.01), DJ1=-45:445, SJ2=-50:440, SJ3=10:500, SJ4=-200:290, DJ2=-150:340, DJ9=100:590, SJ21=-300:190, SJ32=-100:390) 

# Convert data to long format
Probes.m = melt(Probes, id.var="Days")

# Reorder factor levels so "D's" and "S's" are grouped together
Probes.m$variable = factor(Probes.m$variable, 
                           levels=sort(unique(as.character(Probes.m$variable))))

ggplot(Probes.m, aes(Days, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=rep(c("orange","brown"), c(3,5))) +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=Probes.m %>% group_by(variable) %>% filter(value==max(value)),
            aes(label=variable, x=Days + 0.1, y=value), size=3, hjust=0) +
  labs(x="x-label", y="y-label") +
  ggtitle("My Title")
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment and the updated data you provided, the issue is that many of your lines exactly overlap, so they plot one on top of the other. You can see this by inspecting your sample data. Also, using your new data and using `geom_text_repel` instead of `geom_text` you can see there are multiple labels for the "same" line, which is really just multiple copies of the same line with different names.

```
ggplot(Probes.m, aes(Days, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=rep(c("orange","brown","red"), c(9,9,8))) +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(data=Probes.m %>% group_by(variable) %>% filter(value==max(value)),
            aes(label=variable, x=Days + 0.1, y=value), size=3) +
  labs(x="x-label", y="y-label") +
  ggtitle("My Title")
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you, this code worked well.  Is there a way I can add labels of the column names to  the individual lines inside the plot?  Then I could have a legend with just the two line colors specifying each depth.

Comment: I've updated the code to add the labels. Note however, that two of them overlap in this case. If that's an issue in your real data, you'll need to shift the overlapping labels around a bit.

Comment: This code worked well except that I can't figure out to add the appropriate label for the y-axis and also a title. I tried changing the word "value" (the current y-axis label) to "Eh" (the label I need), but the code didn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for this solution a while back.  I am using this same base code and trying to modify it for use with another table.  Instead of having just 2 categories (D and S), I now have 3 (D, M, and S) and I have also increased the number of columns for each category.  I've revised the code to: scale_colour_manual(values=rep(c("orange","brown", "red"), c(9,9,8))) +        However, when I make this revision only half of the lines actually end up plotting.  What else would I need to change in the code in order to make this work properly?  Thanks for your help. @eipi10

Comment: Can you post a sample of the new data as an update to your question? Please paste the output of `dput(myDataSample)` into your question or just add code to create the data frame, as you did in your original question.

Comment: Thank you, solution worked perfectly.  The values for my real dataset do not actually overlap, so the labels lay out reasonably well.  (The reproducible examples are just a bit easier to create by using continuous number sets.)

Answer (score 1):

Building on answer from @eipi10, to cope with overlapping text you could make use of a new package `ggrepel` which provides a new 'geom' for `ggplot`. [I started answering this earlier using `tidyr` instead of `reshape2` and don't have reputation to comment yet so posting this as new answer]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

Probes <- data.frame(Days=seq(0.01, 4.91, 0.01), DJ1=-45:445, SJ2=-50:440, SJ3=10:500, SJ4=-200:290, DJ2=-150:340, DJ9=100:590, SJ21=-300:190, SJ32=-100:390)

tidiedProbes <-
  Probes %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = probeRef, value = `Eh (mV)`, - Days) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lineColour = ifelse(substring(probeRef, 1, 1) == "D", "D", "S"))

dataForLabels <-
  tidiedProbes %>%
  filter(Days == max(Days))

newPlot <- 
  tidiedProbes %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = Days, y = `Eh (mV)`, colour = lineColour, group = probeRef)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "brown")) +
  geom_text_repel(
      data = dataForLabels, 
      aes(x = Days, y = `Eh (mV)`, label = probeRef)) +
  ggtitle("Depth in Sediments - 4.5 cm") + 
  xlab("Elapsed Time (days)") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
newPlot
```

[Don't have reputation for posting images yet but hopefully plot looks as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7KHd.jpg)

Comment: I ended up ultimately going with this answer since it has both the labels and the legend I am hoping for. A question to help me understand the code a little better so I can repeat it for other dataframes: In the line (substring(probeRef, 1, 1) == "D", "D", "S")), why are there 3 letters specified when there are only 2 categories (D and S).  The answer turned out how I wanted, but I found this strange.

Comment: And also, how can I change the text in the legend to say "4 cm" for orange and "1 cm" for brown? Rather than D and S as the legend says now.

Comment: The line you're referring to is part of an ifelse function. So substring gets first letter and then the ifelse checks if it's a "D", in which case it returns (the second) "D" else it returns "S".  To change labels just amend the second "D" and the "S".